# Is it possible to train a machine learning model to predict the next prime number?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, algorithms

As there are no patterns to prime numbers. Is there any way in which ML could predict it?

Comment: Well the gaps between the primes do tend to increase for larger numbers--put differently, primes appear with lower probability for increasingly large numbers--so there is some sort of weak pattern.

Comment: There are plenty of patterns in the prime numbers.  No prime number is even except 2.  In any triple of odd numbers (n, n+2, n+4) at least one is divisible by three.  Etc.

Answer (score 3):

Search for mathematical formulae (in a restricted alphabet) which satisfies the data. Basically, the hypothesis space is the set of all valid formulae.

For example, $\min \{z \in \mathbb{N}\ |\ 
(z > x) \wedge (\not \exists y: (1 < y < z) \wedge (y | z)) \}$ predicts the next prime after $x$.

Given that I've used 9 unique symbols here -- and a total of 19 symbols, this seems not *too* intractable a search space -- and there may be an even more compact solution.

The simplest algorithm would be a brute force search in ascending length, although you could get clever about it and try some sort of genetic algorithm. The search concludes when you find a formula which satisfies all of your test cases, at which point you should've learned a perfect predictor -- given that you use sufficiently many test cases, I doubt there is a shorter incorrect formula than the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

With which accuracy ? And with which (algorithmic) complexity ?

One can extract "features" from an integer (with a constant time) :

- Does it end by 2 ?
- Does it end by 5 ?
- Does it end by ... ?
- Is the sum of its number a multiple of 3 ?
- Is the sum of its number a multiple of 11 ?

And train any model on these features (random forest...), the label being "is my number prime".

I guess with this you would be much better than a random classifier.

Now you can add more complex features (but they may be longer to evaluate than simply check from being prime)

- Is it a square of an integer ?
- Is it a Mersenne number ?
- Does it have the form $3k+1$ ? (or any other form)
- ...